# Unzip files using wildcards

Tags: vbscript, wildcard, unzip

I am basically trying to loop through my working folder to pick up any files that begin with 'Health' and unzip them in the same folder. The problem I have is that the code runs but I'm not getting any unzipped files nor am I getting any errors, can someone please help?

```
Sub Unzip()
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Jimbo\Documents\Process\_ThisWeek").Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "zip" And Left(f.Name, 3) = "Health" Then
      Unzip f.Path, "C:\Users\Jimbo\Documents\Process\_ThisWeek"
    End If

    'If the extraction location does not exist create it
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If NOT fso.FolderExists(f.path) Then
      fso.CreateFolder(f.path)
    End If

    'Extract the contants of the zip file
    set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    set FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(f.name).items
    objShell.NameSpace(f.path).CopyHere(f.name)

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely you don't get an error, because you never call the procedure (assuming what you posted is your entire code). If you did call the procedure you'd probably get an error "file already exists", because `f` is a file object, so `fso.FolderExists(f.Path)` will return `False`, and `fso.CreateFolder(f.Path)` is trying to replace the file with a folder of the same name. Which doesn't work. There are several other issues with your code, too.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks for the reply, i must admit i am totally new to VBS, is there any chance you can start me off please?

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not the right place to provide you with a tutorial. Use your preferred search engine to find one of those.

Comment: Its ok Ansgar, I wasnt expecting a tutorial, i just thought if it was 1 line out of place or a quick fix you could have told me what to change. Back to the drawing board.